# Size of PDF breaks FastAPI using python-multipart?

Tags: pdf, multipartform-data, fastapi

I am trying to upload a **PDF to FastAPI**. After turning the PDF into a base64-blob and storing it in a txt-file, I POST this file to FastAPI using Postman.

This is my server-side code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import base64

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = await file.read()
    blob = base64.b64decode(contents)
    pdf = open('result.pdf','wb')
    pdf.write(blob)
    pdf.close()
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

This procedure works fine for a single-page PDF document of size 279KB (blob-size: 372KB), but it doesn't for a multi-page document of size 1.8MB (blob-size: 2.4MB).

When I try, I get the following WARNING and a 400 bad request response (along with the reseponse "detail": "There was an error parsing the body"):
"Did not find boundary character 55 at index 2"

I'm sure there must be an explanation for this behavior? Maybe it has something to do with async?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Upload File using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048825/how-to-upload-file-using-fastapi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with saving the file using `open()`.

For large files `pdf.close()` will execute before `pdf.write()` has finished saving all the contents of the file.

In order to ensure the whole file being written before it is closed, use `with` such as this:

```
with open('failed.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(blob)
```

Using the `with` you will not need to `close()` after writing. `with` should also be considered best practice over saving the file into a local variable.