# How to Upload File using FastAPI?

Tags: python, file-upload, fastapi, starlette

I am using FastAPI to upload a file according to the official documentation, as shown below:

```
@app.post("/create_file")
async def create_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
      file2store = await file.read()
      # some code to store the BytesIO(file2store) to the other database
```

When I send a request using Python requests library, as shown below:

```
f = open(".../file.txt", 'rb')
files = {"file": (f.name, f, "multipart/form-data")}
requests.post(url="SERVER_URL/create_file", files=files)
```

the `file2store` variable is always empty. Sometimes (rarely seen), it can get the file bytes, but almost all the time it is empty, so I can't restore the file on the other database.

I also tried the `bytes` rather than `UploadFile`, but I get the same results. Is there something wrong with my code, or is the way I use FastAPI to upload a file wrong?

Comment: Do you have `python-multipart` installed? if it's not go for `pip install python-multipart`

Comment: yes, I have installed that. Sometimes I can upload successfully, but it happened rarely.

Comment: Is it happening on a specific file type?

Comment: I tried docx, txt, yaml, png file, all of them have the same problem. And I just found that when I firstly upload a new file, it can upload successfully, but when I upload it at the second time (or more), it failed.

Comment: I know the reason. Thanks for inspiring me. I just use `f = open(file)` method once, and when I send the request several times, the f will be closed after the first time. Thank you agin for helping me.

Answer (score 101):

First, as per [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#request-files), you need to install [`python-multipart`](https://github.com/andrew-d/python-multipart)—if you haven't already—as uploaded files are sent as "form data". For instance:

```
pip install python-multipart
```

The below examples use the `.file` attribute of the [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) object to get the actual Python file (i.e., [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile)), which allows you to call `SpooledTemporaryFile`'s methods, such as `.read()` and `.close()`, without having to `await` them. It is important, however, to define your endpoint with `def` in this case—otherwise, such operations would block the server until they are completed, if the endpoint was defined with `async def`. In FastAPI, a normal `def` endpoint [is run in an external threadpool that is then awaited, instead of being called directly (as it would block the server)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#path-operation-functions).

The `SpooledTemporaryFile` used by FastAPI/Starlette has the `max_size` attribute set to 1 MB, meaning that the data are spooled in memory until the file size exceeds 1 MB, at which point the data are written to a temporary file on disk, under the OS's temp directory. Hence, if you uploaded a file larger than 1 MB, it wouldn't be stored in memory, and calling `file.file.read()` would actually read the data from disk into memory. Thus, if the file is too large to fit into your server's RAM, you should rather read the file in chunks and process one chunk at a time, as described in "Read the File in chunks" section below. You may also have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804), which demonstrates another approach to **upload a large file in chunks**, using Starlette's `.stream()` method and `streaming-form-data` package that allows parsing streaming `multipart/form-data` chunks, which results in considerably minimising the time required to upload files.

If you have to define your endpoint with `async def`—as you might need to `await` for some other coroutines inside your route—then you should rather use *asynchronous* reading and writing of the contents, as demonstrated in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804). Moreover, if you need to send additional data (such as `JSON` data) together with uploading the file(s), please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804). I would also suggest you have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), which explains the difference between `def` and `async def` endpoints.

### Upload Single File

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()

    return {"message": f"Successfully uploaded {file.filename}"}
```

###### Read the File in chunks

As described earlier and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804), if the file is too big to fit into memory—for instance, if you have 8GB of RAM, you can't load a 50GB file (not to mention that the available RAM will always be less than the total amount installed on your machine, as other applications will be using some of the RAM)—you should rather load the file into memory in chunks and process the data one chunk at a time. This method, however, may take longer to complete, depending on the chunk size you choose—in the example below, the chunk size is `1024 * 1024` bytes (i.e., 1MB). You can adjust the chunk size as desired.

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
        
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
            while contents := file.file.read(1024 * 1024):
                f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()

    return {"message": f"Successfully uploaded {file.filename}"}
```

Another option would be to use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj), which is used to copy the contents of a [`file-like`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object to another `file-like` object (have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73365632/17865804) too). By default, the data is read in chunks with the default buffer (chunk) size being 1MB (i.e., `1024 * 1024` bytes) for Windows and 64KB for other platforms, as shown in the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fa03b1b0708d5d74630c351ec9abd2aac7550da/Lib/shutil.py#L42). You can specify the buffer size by passing the optional `length` parameter. Note: If negative `length` value is passed, the entire contents of the file will be read instead—see [`f.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) as well, which `.copyfileobj()` uses under the hood (as can be seen in the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fa03b1b0708d5d74630c351ec9abd2aac7550da/Lib/shutil.py#L190)).

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
import shutil
        
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, f)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        
    return {"message": f"Successfully uploaded {file.filename}"}
```

**test.py**

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
file = {'file': open('images/1.png', 'rb')}
resp = requests.post(url=url, files=file) 
print(resp.json())
```

For an HTML `<form>` example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797993/17865804).

### Upload Multiple (List of) Files

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
from typing import List

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    for file in files:
        try:
            contents = file.file.read()
            with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(contents)
        except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file(s)"}
        finally:
            file.file.close()

    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {[file.filename for file in files]}"}
```

###### Read the Files in chunks

As  described earlier in this answer, if you expect some rather large file(s) and don't have enough RAM to accommodate all the data from the beginning to the end, you should rather load the file into memory in chunks, thus processing the data one chunk at a time (Note: adjust the chunk size as desired, below that is `1024 * 1024` bytes).

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
from typing import List

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    for file in files:
        try:
            with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
                while contents := file.file.read(1024 * 1024):
                    f.write(contents)
        except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file(s)"}
        finally:
            file.file.close()
            
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {[file.filename for file in files]}"}
```

or, using `shutil.copyfileobj()`:

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
from typing import List
import shutil

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    for file in files:
        try:
            with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, f)
        except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file(s)"}
        finally:
            file.file.close()

    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {[file.filename for file in files]}"}
```

**test.py**

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
files = [('files', open('images/1.png', 'rb')), ('files', open('images/2.png', 'rb'))]
resp = requests.post(url=url, files=files) 
print(resp.json())
```

For an HTML `<form>` example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797993/17865804).

Comment: thanks for highlighting the difference between `def` and `async def` !

Comment: I have a question regarding the upload of large files via chunking. If I understand corretly the entire file will be send to the server so is has to be stored in memory on server side. If the file is already in memory anyway why is it still needed to read/write the file in chunks instead of reading/writing the file directly? I thought the chunking process reduces the amount of data that is stored in memory

Comment: @MrNetherlands FastAPI/Starlette uses a `SpooledTemporaryFile` with the `max_size` attribute set to 1 MB, meaning that the data are spooled in memory until the file size exceeds 1 MB, at which point the data are written to a temp directory on disk. Hence, if you uploaded a file larger than 1 MB, it wouldn't be stored in memory, and calling `file.file.read()` would actually read the data from disk into memory. Thus, if the file is too large to fit into your computer's RAM, you should rather read the file in chunks and process one chunk at a time.

Comment: @MrNetherlands Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) (see Update section) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804), which explain the above in detail and provide furher solutions for uploading large files, if you found using `UploadFile` being quite slow. I would also suggest going through all the references included in the linked answers above, which will give you a better understanding on how FastAPI works under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

```
@app.post("/create_file/")
async def image(image: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(image.file)
    # print('../'+os.path.isdir(os.getcwd()+"images"),"*************")
    try:
        os.mkdir("images")
        print(os.getcwd())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) 
    file_name = os.getcwd()+"/images/"+image.filename.replace(" ", "-")
    with open(file_name,'wb+') as f:
        f.write(image.file.read())
        f.close()
   file = jsonable_encoder({"imagePath":file_name})
   new_image = await add_image(file)
   return {"filename": new_image}
```

Comment: Please explain how your code solves the problem.