# How to get file path from UploadFile in FastAPI?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, fastapi

Basically, I'm trying to create an endpoint to Upload files to Amazon S3.

```
async def upload_files(filepath: str, upload_file_list: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    for upload_file in upload_file_list:
        abs_file_path = "/manual/path/works" + upload_file.path
        # Replace above line to get absolute file path from UploadFile
        response = s3_client.upload_file(abs_file_path,bucket_name,
                                                   os.path.join(dest_path, upload_file.filename))
```

Above is my code to upload multiple files to the S3 bucket.
`s3_client.upload_file()` accepts an absolute file path of the file to upload.
It is working when I manually put the full path.

This, however, didn't work:

```
response = s3_client.upload_file(upload_file.filename, bucket_name,
                                                   os.path.join(dest_path, upload_file.filename))
```

Is there a way to get this absolute path in FastAPI? Or, any alternative with `temp_path` without copying or writing the file?

If not, then any alternative with `boto3` to upload files to S3 using FastAPI?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580229/how-to-save-uploadfile-in-fastapi

Answer (score 1):

[`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) uses Python's [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), which is a "file stored in memory", and "is destroyed as soon as it is closed". You can either read the file contents (i.e., using `contents = file.file.read()` or for `async` read/write have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530)), and then upload these bytes to your server (if it permits), or copy the contents of the uploaded file into a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520522/how-can-i-read-uploadfile-in-fastapi/70653605#70653605). Unlike `SpooledTemporaryFile`, a `NamedTemporaryFile` "is guaranteed to have a visible name in the file system" that "can be used to open the file". That name can be retrieved from the `name` attribute (i.e., `temp.name`). Example:

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    try:
        try:
            contents = file.file.read()
            with temp as f:
                f.write(contents);
        except Exception:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Error on uploading the file')
        finally:
            file.file.close()
            
        # Here, upload the file to your S3 service using `temp.name`
        s3_client.upload_file(temp.name, 'local', 'myfile.txt')
        
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    finally:
        #temp.close()  # the `with` statement above takes care of closing the file
        os.remove(temp.name)  # Delete temp file
```

### Update

Additionally, one can access the actual Python file using the `.file` attribute. As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile):

> `file`: A [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) (a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object). This is the actual
> Python file that you can pass directly to other functions or libraries
> that expect a "file-like" object.

Thus, you could also try using `upload_fileobj` function and passing `upload_file.file`:

```
 response = s3_client.upload_fileobj(upload_file.file, bucket_name, os.path.join(dest_path, upload_file.filename))
```

or, passing a file-like object using the `._file` attribute of the [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), which returns either an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) or [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) object (depending on whether binary or text mode was specified).

```
 response = s3_client.upload_fileobj(upload_file.file._file, bucket_name, os.path.join(dest_path, upload_file.filename))
```

### Update 2

You could even keep the bytes in an in-memory buffer (i.e., [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)), use it to upload the contents to the S3 bucket, and finally close it ("*The buffer is discarded when the `close()` method is called*."). Remember to call `seek(0)` method to reset the cursor back to the beginning of the file after you finish writing to the `BytesIO` stream.

```
contents = file.file.read()
temp_file = io.BytesIO()
temp_file.write(contents)
temp_file.seek(0)
s3_client.upload_fileobj(temp_file, bucket_name, os.path.join(dest_path, upload_file.filename))
temp_file.close()
```