# Reuse function that validates file size [fastapi]

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm very new to FastAPI.
I want to validate the file type and the file size of an uploaded file and raise `Exception` if it's above the size and doesn't match the type. This file will be uploaded to `S3`
This is what my code looks like

```
@router.post("/upload/", status_code=200, description="***** Upload customer document asset to S3 *****")
async def upload(
        document_type: DocumentEnum,
        customer_id: UUID,
        current_user=Depends(get_current_user),
        fileobject: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    # delete the file from memory and rollover to disk to save unnecessary memory space
    fileobject.file.rollover()
    fileobject.file.flush()

    valid_types = [
        'image/png',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/bmp',
        'application/pdf'
    ]
    await validate_file(fileobject, 5000000, valid_types)

    # .... Proceed to upload file
```

My `validate_file` function looks like this

```
async def validate_file(file: UploadFile, max_size: int = None, mime_types: list = None):
    """
    Validate a file by checking the size and mime types a.k.a file types
    """
    if mime_types and file.content_type not in mime_types:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="You can only upload pdf and image for document"
        )
    if max_size:
        size = await file.read()
        if len(size) > max_size:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_413_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE,
                detail="File size is too big. Limit is 5mb"
            )

    return file
```

Now when the file gets uploaded to `S3`, it's always `0 bytes` in size.
However, if I exclude the file size checking from `validate_file` function, then the original file gets uploaded and there's no problem.
If the `validate_file` function is like this, then it gets uploaded fine

```
async def validate_file(file: UploadFile, max_size: int = None, mime_types: list = None):
    """
    Validate a file by checking the size and mime types a.k.a file types
    """
    if mime_types and file.content_type not in mime_types:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="You can only upload pdf and image for document"
        )
            )

    return file
```

I've no idea why this happens. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520522/how-can-i-read-uploadfile-in-fastapi/70653605#70653605), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579109/how-to-get-file-path-from-uploadfile-in-fastapi/70665801#70665801) answer. They should point you on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `read` on a file, the current file pointer will be at the end of what you read. When you (or the library) call `read` the second time, the internal file pointer will already be at the end of the file.

You can use `await file.seek(0)` to put the file pointer at the start of the file, so that the next read will read the same content again:

```
if max_size:
    size = await file.read()

    if len(size) > max_size:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_413_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE,
            detail="File size is too big. Limit is 5mb"
        )

    await file.seek(0)

return file
```

You might also want to explicitly resolve the mime type of the file instead of trusting what the user says the file is - you can [use `mimetypes.guess_type` or something similar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this function to validate files

```py
import filetype
from typing import IO
from fastapi import HTTPException, status


async def validate_file_size_type(file: IO):
    FILE_SIZE = 2097152  # 2MB

    accepted_file_types = [
        "image/png",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/jpg",
        "png",
        "jpeg",
        "jpg",
    ]

    file_info = filetype.guess(file.file)

    if file_info is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_415_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE,
            detail="Unable to determine file type",
        )

    detected_content_type = file_info.extension.lower()

    if (
        file.content_type not in accepted_file_types
        or detected_content_type not in accepted_file_types
    ):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_415_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE,
            detail="Unsupported file type",
        )

    real_file_size = 0
    for chunk in file.file:
        real_file_size += len(chunk)
        if real_file_size > FILE_SIZE:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_413_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE, detail="Too large")
            
    # return the pointer back to the starting point so that the next read starts from the starting point
    await file.seek(0)
```