# Python read/write vs shutil copy

Tags: python, file, io, fastapi, shutil

I need to save files uploaded to my server (Max file size is 10MB) and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63581187/14190526), which works perfectly. However, I'm wondering what is the point of using the `shutil` module, and what is the difference between this:

```py
file_location = f"files/{uploaded_file.filename}"
with open(file_location, "wb+") as file_object:
    file_object.write(uploaded_file.file.read())
```

and this:

```py
import shutil

file_location = f"files/{uploaded_file.filename}"
with open(file_location, "wb+") as file_object:
    shutil.copyfileobj(uploaded_file.file, file_object)
```

During my programming experience, I came across `shutil` module multiple times, but still can't figure out what its benefits are over `read()` and `write()` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method requires the whole file be in memory.  `shutil` copies in chunks so you can copy files larger than memory.  Also, `shutil` has routines to copy files by name so you don't have to open them at all, and it can preserve the permissions, ownership, and creation/modification/access timestamps.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to highlight a few points with regards to OP's question and the (currently accepted) answer by @Tim Roberts:

1. *"shutil copies in chunks so you can copy files larger than memory"*. You can also copy a file in chunks using `read()`—please
   have a look at the short example below, as well as [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) answer for more
   details—just like you can load the whole file into memory
   using [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj), by giving a negative `length` value.

   ```py
   with open(uploaded_file.filename, 'wb') as f:
       while contents := uploaded_file.file.read(1024 * 1024):  # adjust the chunk size as desired
           f.write(contents)
   ```

   Under the hood, `copyfileob()` uses a very similar approach to the above, utilising `read()` and `write()` [methods of file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects); hence, it would make little difference, if you used one over the other. The [source code of  `copyfileob()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fa03b1b0708d5d74630c351ec9abd2aac7550da/Lib/shutil.py#L190) can be seen below. The default buffer size, i.e., `COPY_BUFSIZE` below, is set to `1MB` (`1024 *1024` bytes), if it is running on Wnidows, or `64KB` (`64 * 1024` bytes) on other platforms (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fa03b1b0708d5d74630c351ec9abd2aac7550da/Lib/shutil.py#L42)).

   ```py
   def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=0):
       """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
       if not length:
           length = COPY_BUFSIZE
       # Localize variable access to minimize overhead.
       fsrc_read = fsrc.read
       fdst_write = fdst.write
       while True:
           buf = fsrc_read(length)
           if not buf:
               break
           fdst_write(buf)
   ```
2. *"`shutil` has routines to copy files by name so you don't have to open them at all..."* Since OP seems to be using [FastAPI
   framework](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) (which is actually
   [Starlette](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) underneath), [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) exposes an actual Python
   [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) (a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object) that you can get using the `.file`
   attribute (source code can be found [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/f6ea760a80d8b109fb6afd1c03e9a33754e6bb5f/starlette/datastructures.py#L426)). When FastAPI/Starlette creates a new instance of `UploadFile`, it already creates the `SpooledTemporaryFile` behind the scenes, which remains open. Hence, since you are dealing with a temporary
   file that has no visible name in the file system—that would otherwise allow you to copy the contents without opening the file using `shutil`—and which is already open, it would make no
   difference using either `read()` or `copyfileobj()`.
3. *"it can preserve the permissions, ownership, and creation/modification/access timestamps."* Even though this is about saving a file uploaded through a web framework—and hence, most of these metadata wouldn't be transfered along with the file—as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html), the above statement is not entirely true:

   > **Warning:** Even the higher-level file copying functions (`shutil.copy()`, `shutil.copy2()`) **cannot** copy all file
   > metadata.
   >
   > On POSIX platforms, this means that **file owner and group are lost
   > as well as ACLs**. On Mac OS, the resource fork and other metadata are
   > **not used**. This means that resources **will be lost** and file type and creator codes **will not be correct**. On Windows, **file
   > owners,
   > ACLs and alternate data streams are not copied**.

That being said, there is nothing wrong with using [`copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj). On the contrary, if you are dealing with large files and you would like to avoid loading the entire file into memory—as you may not have enough RAM to accommodate all the data—and you would rather use `copyfileobj()` instead of a similar solution using `read()` method (as described in point 1 above), it is perfectly fine to use `shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)`. Besides, `copyfileobj()` has been offered (since Python 3.8) as an alternative [platform-dependent efficient copy operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil-platform-dependent-efficient-copy-operations). You can change the default buffer size through adjusting the `length` argument in [`copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj).

#### Note

If `copyfileobj()` is used inside a FastAPI `def` (sync) endpoint, it is perfectly fine, as a normal `def` endpoint in FastAPI [is run in an external threadpool that is then awaited, instead of being called directly (as it would block the server)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#path-operation-functions). On the other hand, `async def` endpoints run on the main (single) thread, and thus, calling such a method, i.e., `copyfileobj()`, that performs blocking I/O operations (as shown in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fa03b1b0708d5d74630c351ec9abd2aac7550da/Lib/shutil.py#L190)) would result in blocking the entire server (for more information on `def` vs `async def`, please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)). Hence, if you are about to call `copyfileobj()` from within an `async def` endpoint, you should make sure to run this operation—as well as all other file operations, such as `open()` and `close()`—in a separate thread to ensure that the main thread (where coroutines are run) does not get blocked. You can do that using Starlette's [`run_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/concurrency.py#L35), which is also used by FastAPI internally when you call the `async` methods of the `UploadFile` object, as shown [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/f6ea760a80d8b109fb6afd1c03e9a33754e6bb5f/starlette/datastructures.py#L462). For instance:

```py
await run_in_threadpool(shutil.copyfileobj, fsrc, fdst)
```

For more details and code examples, please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804).