# Should I use shutil.copy() inside a with block

Tags: python, shutil

So every newbie to Python learns that it is a good thing to put file operations such as reading from and writing to a file inside a `with` block such as

```
with open(path, 'w') as f: 
   f.write(s)
```

But is the same true if I use `shutil`-functions e. g. to copy files as used in the first example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732361/python-read-write-vs-shutil-copy):

```
file_location = f"files/{uploaded_file.filename}"
with open(file_location, "wb+") as file_object:
    file_object.write(uploaded_file.file.read())
```

I tried to find an answer to this question on stackoverflow and through google, but I couldn't find any specific information on it. So maybe it is a very obvious question and I just don't get it - or maybe I searched at the wrong places.

So any hint or answer is much appreciated!

Comment: If you have to open a file object it is always good to use `with` to make sure the file is closed properly even if errors occur within the with-block.  If you are using a `shutil` function that doesn't require an opened file handle (e.g. shutil.copyfile) there is nothing that needs a with-block.

Comment: thanks a lot, that basically answers my question.