# Subsystem python cannot point to the file

Tags: python, subprocess, fastapi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I build the backend using fastapi like this :

`process.py`

```
import shutil
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, HTTPException, UploadFile
import os
import subprocess
from pydantic import ValidationError


app=FastAPI()

def validate_file_type(filename: str):
    allowed_extensions = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in allowed_extensions:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail="Only JPEG and PNG files allowed")

@app.post("/process-images")
async def process_images(img1: UploadFile=File(...), img2:UploadFile=File(...)):
    try:
        validate_file_type(img1.filename)
        validate_file_type(img2.filename)
        # Process image 1
        with open(f"{img1.filename}", "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(img1.file, buffer)

        # Process image 2
        with open(f"{img2.filename}", "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(img2.file, buffer)
        
        subprocess.run(['wsl','./process', '-m', ' 1 ', ' -L ', '{img1.filename}' ,' -R ','{img2.filename}'])
        return {"message":"Send successful"} #testing this point
    except ValidationError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail=str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal server error")
```

Ther `process` file still run but subsystem cannot point to the `img1` file and `img2` file, but it still exist in folder:

```
- Root
  |- 1.png
  |- 2.png
  |- server.py
  |- process
```

In this situation the `img1` and `img2` is `1.png` and `2.png`.

What did I do wrong?

Try to change with the specific path but not work

Comment: Shouldn't it be `f'{img1.filename}'` or `f'"{img1.filename}"'` or `img1.filename` instead of `'{img1.filename}'`? It seems to me that you passing a string `{img1.filename}` each time, not the image's filename.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to run blocking operations, such as `shutil.copyfileobj()` inside `async def` endpoints. I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73365632/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), as well as every reference included in them, in order to better understand FastAPI and how to deal with uploading files when using it.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
subprocess.run(['wsl','./process', '-m', ' 1 ', ' -L ', '{img1.filename}' ,' -R ','{img2.filename}'])
```

you're literally passing in the string `"{img1.filename}"` as a filename.

I suspect you mean

```py
subprocess.run(
    [
        "wsl",
        "./process",
        "-m",
        "1",
        "-L",
        img1.filename,
        "-R",
        img2.filename,
    ],
    check=True,  # raise if the process fails
)
```

(or if you're not sure those `filename`s are `str`s, wrap them in `str()`.)