# INFO: 127.0.0.1:52154 - "POST /api/v1/contents/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity Fastapi and Svelte

Tags: python, fastapi, svelte

I tried to upload image to my backend server, I kept getting INFO:     127.0.0.1:52154 - "POST /api/v1/contents/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity. I tried it with django rest framework, I kept getting errors, thought it has something to do with the framework, I tried fastapi, yet still getting similar error. it seems it has something to do with svelte, but for some reason I couldn't figure it out.

I added header, yet kept getting as same error

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
},
```

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
  import type { SubmitFunction } from '@sveltejs/kit';
  import { addAlert } from '$lib/store/store';
  import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
  import type { Post } from '$lib/types';

  export let showPostModal: boolean;
  export let categories: any[];
  export let post: Post | null = null;
  export let actions: string;
  let errors: any = {};
  let loading: boolean = false;
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
  const closeModal = () => {
    dispatch('close');
  };

  const submit: SubmitFunction = ({ formData }) => {
    loading = true;

    return async ({ result, update }) => {
      try {
        if (result.status === 200) {
          console.log("200 status...........", result);

          dispatch('postCreated', result.data.newPost);
          addAlert({
            message: `${post ? 'Post edited successfully' : 'New post created successfully'}`,
            type: 'success'
          });
          closeModal();
        } else if (result.status === 400) {
          console.log("400 error...........", result);
          errors = result?.data.errors;
        } else if (result.status === 500) {
          console.log("500 error..............", result);
          addAlert({ message: `${result.data.message}`, type: 'error' });
        }
      } finally {
        loading = false;
        update();
      }
    };
  };

  onMount(() => {
    categories = categories.map((category: any) => ({
      label: category.name,
      value: category.uuid
    }));
  });

  let photo: any[];
  let category: string = post ? post.category_name : '';
  let description: string = post ? post.description : '';
  let title: string = post ? post.title : '';
  $: author_name = post ? post.author_name : $currentUser?.name;

  console.log("author name...", currentUser.name, author_name);
</script>

{#if showPostModal}
  <div
    class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center z-50 left-0 transition-transform duration-300"
    in:fly={{ y: -100 }}
    out:fly={{ y: -100 }}
    class:slide-transition={{ showPostModal }}
  >
    <div
      on:click={closeModal}
      on:keydown={closeModal}
      class="w-full cursor-pointer h-full absolute bg-black opacity-30"
    />
    <div
      on:keydown={closeModal}
      class="absolute w-8 z-[100] h-8 items-center flex justify-center cursor-pointer bg-white rounded-full font-bold top-3 right-3 text-3xl text-rose-600"
      on:click={closeModal}
    >
      <iconify-icon icon="material-symbols:cancel" />
    </div>
    <div
      class="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 mx-auto sm:max-w-xl md:max-w-[80rem]"
    >
      <form
        method="post"
        use:enhance={submit}
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action={actions}
        class="p-4 text-center flex h-[500px] flex-col gap-5 overflow-y-auto"
      >
        <h1 class="mb-1 text-xl font-bold">{post ? 'Edit Post' : 'Create Post'}</h1>

        <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*"/>

        <div class="mt-5 flex justify-center w-full">
          <button
            type="submit"
            class="py-2.5 outline-none px-4 inline-flex justify-center items-center gap-2 rounded-md border border-transparent font-semibold bg-primary text-white hover:bg-blue-900 w-full focus:ring-offset-2 transition-all text-sm"
          >
            {#if loading}
              <iconify-icon icon="line-md:loading-loop" width="20" />{:else}
              {post ? 'Edit Post' : 'Create Post'}
            {/if}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{/if}
</script>
```

```
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, HTTPException, status

@router.post("/contents/")
async def create_content(photo: UploadFile = File(..., max_length=10*1024*1024)):
    print(photo, photo.filename, photo.content_type)
```

Comment: The body of the 422 error will tell you exactly what part of the submitted data that didn't match the expected format. You should also be able to look at the submitted data in your browser's development tools (the network tab) and see exactly how the data is being posted (whether it's posted as regular form data or as JSON serialized data).

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711008/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797993/17865804)

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Your response was really helpful