# FastAPI/Mangum JSON decode error when uploading multiple files

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests, fastapi, starlette

I'm trying to create a serverless file upload API using FastAPI/Mangum and am running into a strange JSON decoding issue when attempting to follow the example in the docs.

Here is my code:

```py
# main.py
import os

from typing import List
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from mangum import Mangum

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def main():
    content = """
    <body>
     <form action="/registration/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input name="files" type="file" multiple>
      <input type="submit">
     </form>
    </body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)

@app.post("/registration/create")
async def create_registration(files: List[UploadFile]):
    return {"file_len": len(files)}

handler = Mangum(app)
```

```py
# test_main.py
from urllib import response
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_registration():
    files = [('files', ('example.txt', open('example.txt', 'rb'), 'text/plain'))]
    response = client.post("/registration/create", files=files)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

When I run the test or attempt to `POST` files using the web page example, I receive a JSON decoding error and the request fails with `422` status code error:

```
{
 "detail":
   [{"loc":["body",0],
     "msg":"Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
     "type":"value_error.jsondecode",
     "ctx": {
       "msg": "Expecting value",
       "doc": "\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\\"files\\"; filename=\\"example.txt\\"\\r\\nContent-Type: text/plain\\r\\n\\r\\nexample text in the file\n",
     "pos":0,
     "lineno":1,
     "colno":1
  }
 }]
}
```

Here is the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#multiple-file-uploads) page I am referencing.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get simply shows that your FastAPI endpoint, in the way it is defined, is expecting JSON data, and this is because you didn't specify the type of `UploadFile`, i.e., using  `= File(...)`. Hence, FastAPI interprets and expects `List[UploadFile]` as JSON body instead.

Your endpoint should instead look like this:

```py
from fastapi import File

@app.post("/registration/create")
async def create_registration(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    return {"file_len": len(files)}
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) answer for more details.

## Update

In the latest version of FastAPI, you can [define a file parameter with a type of `UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#file-parameters-with-uploadfile) **without** having to use `= File()` or `= File(...)` in the default value of the parameter. Hence, the below should also be working as expected:

```py
@app.post("/registration/create")
async def create_registration(files: List[UploadFile]):
    return {"file_len": len(files)}
```

##### Working Example

This example is based on FastAPI's documentation on [Multiple File Uploads](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#multiple-file-uploads).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/files/")
async def create_files(files: List[UploadFile]):
    return {"filenames": [file.filename for file in files]}


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    content = """
    <body>
    <form action="/files/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="files" type="file" multiple>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)
```