# How to save an uploaded image to FastAPI using Python Imaging Library (PIL)?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, fastapi

I am using image compression to reduce the image size. When submitting the post request, I am not getting any error, but can't figure out why the images do not get saved. Here is my code:

```py
@app.post("/post_ads")
async def create_upload_files(title: str = Form(),body: str = Form(), 
    db: Session = Depends(get_db), files: list[UploadFile] = File(description="Multiple files as UploadFile")):
    for file in files:
        im = Image.open(file.file)
        im = im.convert("RGB")
        im_io = BytesIO()
        im = im.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=50)
```

Comment: Your image is saved in RAM inside `im_io`. Change last line to `im.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=50) `

Comment: @Mark Setchell this is my last line `im.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=50) `  what I need to be changed? I tried `im = im.save('JPEG', quality=50)` getting this error `ValueError: unknown file extension:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`PIL.Image.open()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) takes as `fp` argumnet the following:

> `fp` – A `filename` (string), `pathlib.Path` object or a `file` object. The
> file object must implement `file.read()`, `file.seek()`, and
> `file.tell()` methods, and be opened in binary mode.

Using a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) stream, you would need to have something like the below (as shown in **client side** of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804)):

```
Image.open(io.BytesIO(file.file.read()))
```

However, you don't really have to use an in-memory bytes buffer, as you can get the actual file object using the `.file` attribute of [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile). As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile):

> `file`: A [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) (a [`file-like`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object).
> This is the actual Python file that you can pass directly to other
> functions or libraries that expect a "file-like" object.

##### Example - Saving image to disk:

```py
# ...
from fastapi import HTTPException
from PIL import Image

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File()):
    try:        
        im = Image.open(file.file)
        if im.mode in ("RGBA", "P"): 
            im = im.convert("RGB")
        im.save('out.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=50) 
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        im.close()
```

##### Example - Saving image to an in-memory bytes buffer (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73815575/17865804)):

```py
# ...
from fastapi import HTTPException
from PIL import Image

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File()):
    try:        
        im = Image.open(file.file)
        if im.mode in ("RGBA", "P"): 
            im = im.convert("RGB")
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        im.save(buf, 'JPEG', quality=50)
        # to get the entire bytes of the buffer use:
        contents = buf.getvalue()
        # or, to read from `buf` (which is a file-like object), call this first:
        buf.seek(0)  # to rewind the cursor to the start of the buffer
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        buf.close()
        im.close()
```

For more details and code examples on how to upload files/images using FastAPI, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804). Also, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more information on defining your endpoint with `def` or `async def`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are writing to a `BytesIO` to get an *"in memory"* JPEG without slowing yourself down by writing to disk and cluttering your filesystem.

If so, you want:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

im = Image.open(file.file)
im = im.convert("RGB")
im_io = BytesIO()
# create in-memory JPEG in RAM (not disk)
im.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=50)

# get the JPEG image in a variable called JPEG
JPEG = im_io.get_value()
```