# How to resize image uploaded to FastAPI using Python Imaging Library (PIL)?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, fastapi

I would like to create a FastAPI application for my image classification model. But when I upload the image file, it can not make predictions, because my model is setting the image as `(256,256)`, but the image that gets uploaded is not `(256,256)`. How can I resize the image after uploading and before getting predictions?

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import uvicorn
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

app = FastAPI()

MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("D:/Works/M.6/New Soil/Classification/Model/SoilModel.h5")

CLASS_NAMES = ["Clay", "Loam", "Red","Sandy"]

@app.get("/home")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, Welcome to CropChat"

def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
    img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
    
    predictions = MODEL.predict(img_batch)

    predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
    confidence = np.max(predictions[0])
    return {
        'class': predicted_class,
        'confidence': float(confidence)
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

I tried to use `image.resize`, but it doesn't work.

If you guys have some recommendations for my code please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: that should be working `Image.open(BytesIO(data)).resize((256, 256))`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which `image` object you have used `.resize(dim: tuple)` but dropping the correct way to do, it should be working.
actually, you have to resize before converting to an array.

```
def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    size = (256, 256)
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)).resize(size))
    return image
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is heavily based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73811351/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804).

Note that using a `BytesIO` stream, as shown in your question, would not be necessary. You could instead pass the actual `file` object to `Image.open()`, using the `.file` attribute of `UploadFile` (see the linked answers above for more details). In that case, please make sure to define the endpoint with normal `def` instead of `async def` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details on that topic). If you prefer using `async def`, creating a new `BytesIO()` stream after reading the file bytes using `await file.read()` would also be feasible. Another possible option would be to use [`Image.frombytes()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.frombytes), similar to this [`PIL.Image.frombytes()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes), however, without creating a new image object.

To resize the image, you could use [`Image.resize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize):

> `Image.resize(size, resample=None, box=None, reducing_gap=None)`
>
> Returns a resized copy of this image.
>
> **PARAMETERS**:
>
> - **size** – The requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple: (width, height).
> - ...

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File, HTTPException
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File()):
    try:        
        im = Image.open(file.file)
        
        # resize and save Image
        im = im.resize((256, 256))
        im.save('out.png')
        
        # convert Image to array
        arr = np.asarray(im)
        
        return 'OK'
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        im.close()
```

#### Note

If you would like to **preserve the aspect ratio of the image**, instead of using `im.resize()`, you could use [`Image.thumbnail()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) (an example is also given in the documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails)). However, **note** that using this function might not result in a `256 x 256` image, as you requested (it might instead result in a `256 x 160`, for instance, regardless of the `size` tuple passed to the function).

> `Image.thumbnail(size, resample=Resampling.BICUBIC, reducing_gap=2.0)`
>
> Make this image into a thumbnail. This method modifies the image to contain a thumbnail version of itself, no larger than the given size. This method calculates an appropriate thumbnail size to **preserve the aspect of the image**, calls the `draft()` method to configure the file reader (where applicable), and finally resizes the image.
>
> **Note** that this function modifies the Image object in place. If you
> need to use the full resolution image as well, apply this method to a
> `copy()` of the original image.
>
> **PARAMETERS**:
>
> - **size** – The requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple: (width, height).
> - **resample** – Optional resampling filter. This can be one of `Resampling.NEAREST`, `Resampling.BOX`, `Resampling.BILINEAR`,
>   `Resampling.HAMMING`, `Resampling.BICUBIC` or `Resampling.LANCZOS`. If
>   omitted, it defaults to `Resampling.BICUBIC`. (was `Resampling.NEAREST`
>   prior to version 2.5.0). See: [Filters](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-filters)
> - ...

##### Example

```
im.thumbnail((256, 256), Image.LANCZOS)
im.save('out.png')
```