# How to upload Images in rest API endpoint?

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, yolov8

I am using YOLOv8 model, and creating API for it, I have to pass image in my model, through rest end point.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from pydantic import BaseModel
import app.model.model as model

app = FastAPI()


class FileIn(BaseModel):
    file: UploadFile


class PredictionOut(BaseModel):
    result: list


@app.get("/")
def home():
    return {"health_check": "OK", "model_version": 0.01}


@app.post("/predict/")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    try:
        content = file.file.read()
        print(type(content))
        result = model.load_yolo_v8(content)

        return {"result": result}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
```

It is throwing me error,

```
{
    "error": "Unsupported image type. For supported types see https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict"
}
```

I have tried my model and given it path as a **string**, and it works but when I do hit request after making API it fails, it is taking image file type as **bytes** from postman, yolov8 does not support bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@app.post("/predict/")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    try:
        content_byte = file.file.read()
        content_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(content_byte))
        result = model.predict_result(content_image)

        return {"result": result}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
```

here's how I did it:

**content_byte = file.file.read()**

**content_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(content_byte))**

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73811351/17865804). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73815575/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76645939/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) helpful as well.

Comment: can you please put your example solution in answer below to this question, I am talking about second comment of your's. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Save image in temp file `path_to_file = /path/to/file with open(path_to_file, 'wb') as f: f.write(file.file.read())`, predict with Yolov8 `prediction = yolov8.predict(path_to_file)`and then remove. `os.remove(path_to_file)`