# Upload multipart-form image as data in FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, web, fastapi

I am trying to write endpoint for image uploading, it will accept just image in base64 format. I have read how to get file from request in FastAPI and implement that in this way:

**server side**

```
@router.post("/v1/installation/{some_identifier}/image")
@db.create_connection
async def upload_installation_image(some_identifier: int, data: UploadFile = File(...)):
    ...
    content = await data.read()
    image_uuid = await save_image(installation.uuid, content, data.content_type)
    
    return {"image_uuid": image_uuid}
```

And its works fine, but in this case I need to send data in this way:

**client side**

```
def test_upload_image(...):
    ...
    response = session.post(
            f"/v1/installation/{relink_serial}/image", files={"file": ("test_file_name.png", data, "image/png")}
        )
    ...
```

But I want to be able to upload image like this:

**client side**

```
def test_upload_image(...):
    ...
    response = session.post(
        f"/v1/installation/{installation_uuid}/image", data=data, headers={"content-type": "image/png"}
    )
```

I have read a lot of articles and other questions, but all of them suggest to use UploadFile and send data as json with `file` or `body` parameter.
Is this even possible, to load just 1 file like in second test I show?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) (see Update section), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804).

Answer (score 1):

I have find solution. Instead of using predefined FastAPI types, I can directly get all data from request object, so my code looks like this:

```
@router.post("/v1/installation/{some_identifier}/image")
@db.create_connection
async def upload_installation_image(some_identifier: int, request: Request):
    ...
    content = await request.body()
    image_uuid = await save_image(installation.uuid, content, content_type)
    
    return {"image_uuid": image_uuid}
```

Thats exactly what I am looking for, because in my case **client app** have send to me whole file in body.