# How to upload file in FastAPI and then access it by URL in the frontend?

Tags: python, api, rest, fastapi

I am learning FastAPI and trying to upload an image file to the server, and then I want to access it by URK in the frontend.

For example, I send a POST request with file `image.png`, and then using a `GET` request I should get a response including the link to the uploaded file.

```json
Response:
{
    "filename": "image.png"
    "url": "127.0.0.1/image.png"
}
```

This is my code so far:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
async def root(file:UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filename":file.filename}


@app.get("/get")
async def root():
    return {
        "filename":file.filename,
        "url":"127.0.0.1/"+file.filename

    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) as well on how to upload and save a file in FastAPI.